# Android read contacts(and details) seems very slow

Tags: android, performance, contacts, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I use the following code to read each contacts along with their details.

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION =
{
    Data._ID,
    Data.MIMETYPE,
    Data.DATA1,
    Data.DATA2,
    Data.DATA3,
    Data.DATA4,
    Data.DATA5,
    Data.DATA6,
    Data.DATA7,
    Data.DATA8,
    Data.DATA9,
    Data.DATA10,
    Data.DATA11,
    Data.DATA12,
    Data.DATA13,
    Data.DATA14,
    Data.DATA15
};    


private static final String SELECTION = Data.LOOKUP_KEY + " = ?";
private String[] mSelectionArgs = { "" };
private static final String SORT_ORDER = Data.MIMETYPE;
private static final int MIME_TYPE_INDEX = 1;
private static final int DISPLAY_NAME_INDEX = 3;//data2
private static final int GIVEN_NAME_INDEX = 3;//data2
private static final int FAMILY_NAME_INDEX = 4;//data3
private static final int MIDDLE_NAME_INDEX = 6;//data5
private static final int ORGANIZATION_INDEX = 2;//data2
private static final int PHONE_TYPE_INDEX = 3;//data2
private static final int PHONE_LABEL_INDEX = 4;//data3
private static final int PHONE_NUMBER_INDEX = 2;//data1
private static final int EMAIL_TYPE_INDEX = 3;//data2
private static final int EMAIL_LABEL_INDEX = 4;//data1
private static final int EMAIL_INDEX = 2;//data1

 private byte[] createJsonData(ArrayList<String> selected) throws JSONException, IOException{

    Log.d("SynchContactActivity", "Time 1: " + java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    int current = 0;
    final String messagePrep = getResources().getString(R.string.progress_message_prep);
    final String messageCompress = getResources().getString(R.string.progress_message_compress);
    final String messageUpload = getResources().getString(R.string.progress_message_upload);

    if(selected == null ){
        selected = getContacts();
    }

    final int count = selected.size();

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(mProgressDialog != null){
                mProgressDialog.setMax(count);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage(messagePrep);
            }
        }
    });

    updateProgress(current);

    JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray contactsArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject contactJSON, phoneJSON, emailJSON;
    JSONArray phonesArray,emailsArray;
    String name, lastName, middleName,organization;

    for (String key : selected) {

        contactJSON = new JSONObject();
        phonesArray = new JSONArray();
        emailsArray = new JSONArray();

        mSelectionArgs[0] = key;
        //Cursor details = managedQuery(Data.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, SELECTION, mSelectionArgs, SORT_ORDER);
        Cursor details = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, SELECTION, mSelectionArgs, SORT_ORDER);

        //initialize null variables
        name = null;
        lastName = null;
        middleName = null;
        organization = null;
        while(details.moveToNext()){
            String mimeType = details.getString(MIME_TYPE_INDEX);

            if(mimeType.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                name = details.getString(GIVEN_NAME_INDEX);
                lastName = details.getString(FAMILY_NAME_INDEX);
                middleName = details.getString(MIDDLE_NAME_INDEX);

            }
            else if(mimeType.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                organization = details.getString(ORGANIZATION_INDEX);
            }               
            else if(mimeType.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                phoneJSON = new JSONObject();
                String phoneNumber = details.getString(PHONE_NUMBER_INDEX);
                int type = details.getInt(PHONE_TYPE_INDEX);
                String typeLabel = phoneTypeMap.get(String.valueOf(type));
                if (typeLabel == null) {
                    typeLabel = details.getString(PHONE_LABEL_INDEX);
                }
                phoneJSON.put("ptype", typeLabel);
                phoneJSON.put("number", phoneNumber);
                phonesArray.put(phoneJSON);
            }
            else if(mimeType.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                emailJSON = new JSONObject();
                String email = details.getString(EMAIL_INDEX);
                int type = details.getInt(EMAIL_TYPE_INDEX);
                String typeLabel = emailTypeMap.get(String.valueOf(type));
                if (typeLabel == null) {
                    typeLabel = details.getString(EMAIL_LABEL_INDEX);
                }
                emailJSON.put("etype", typeLabel);
                emailJSON.put("address",email);
                emailsArray.put(emailJSON);
            }
        }

        contactJSON.put("firstname", name==null?"null":name);
        contactJSON.put("middlename", middleName==null?"null":middleName);
        contactJSON.put("lastname", lastName==null?"null":lastName);
        contactJSON.put("organization", organization==null?"null":organization);
        contactJSON.put("phones", phonesArray);
        contactJSON.put("emails", emailsArray);
        contactsArray.put(contactJSON);
        details.close();
        ++current;
        updateProgress(current);
    }
    root.put("contacts", contactsArray);
    Log.d("SynchContactActivity", "Time 1: " + java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(mProgressDialog != null){
                mProgressDialog.setMessage(messageCompress);
            }
        }
    });
    // to compress
    String json_doc = root.toString();
    byte[] compressed = compress(json_doc);

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(mProgressDialog != null){
                mProgressDialog.setMessage(messageUpload);
            }
        }
    });
    return compressed;
}
```

This code is too slow - that reads 3-4 contacts per second on average. Is this normal or can be optimized?

I think projection might be a good candidate to be optimized but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to tell exactly what you're trying to do, but it looks like you're trying to read data from the Contacts Provider and send it to a server using JSON. I suggest you look at the ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity table, which contains all the data you're probably looking for without the mess of trying to figure out the MIME type of the DATA row you've just retrieved. You're certainly slowing down your app by getting the entire contents of the DATA row.

In addition, you should use a SyncAdapter to do this work. See [Transferring Data Using Sync Adapters](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html)

Comment: Hi, yes I want to do what exactly you said. However, it's slow anyhow whether or not I use MIMETYPE check. The query is the troubled part here.

Answer (score -2):

Reading contacts can be made in 2-5 seconds. See the example app here

[Source code attached](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.prasilabs.contactsreadingexample)

Comment: What about adding a direct link to your code on GitHub, or even better directly add it here? I downloaded that app just because I saw from the screens that there were the GitHub link, to see how you were able to do it in 2-5 sec. The app crashed at launch. For these reasons I don't think this answer is helpful